# How to convert received data to inputstream and outputstream

Tags: java, netty

I have to create TCP/IP server for RPC communications. I'm bound to using a provided java lib that handles all the "rpc" stuff. This lib received HDLC messages that contain protobuf data. The lib itself uses request and response handlers to handle the HDLC and protobuf part. This lib can be used for serial connections as well as networked connections.

We'd like to use netty for the TCP server for this. When calling this lib it expects an `java.io.inputstream` and `java.io.outputstream` in the "RPC" method.

I have a simple blocking setup, in which I create a server socket, and just pass a `socket.getInputStream()` and `socket.getOutputStream()` to the RPC method. Next I need to register a (set) of rpc handlers to this rpc object, and than clients can connect and data can be send. Seems pretty straightforward to me.

I've also setup a netty "echo" server and now I want to use this RPC library with netty. What I'm struggling with is how to convert my received data to the required `InputStream` and how to convert the `OutputStream` of the RPC lib so that it can be send back to the client. Do I need a decoder/encoder, or is there a simpler way to do this? And if so, how do I transform the `ByteBuf` to an `InputStream` and the `OutputStream` back the format that can be send over the network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Inputstream

#### The other api has a readpacket() method

If you library has a readPacket method, you can use the [`ByteBufInputStream`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/index.html?io/netty/buffer/ByteBufInputStream.html) in combination with a [`ReplayingDecoder`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/index.html?io/netty/handler/codec/ReplayingDecoder.html), this is relatively easy to implement:

```java
public class RPCInputHandler extends ReplayingDecoder<Object> {
   RPC upstream = ....;
   protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf buf) throws Exception {
      upstream.readPacket(new ByteBufInputStream(buf));
      state(null);
   }
}
```

#### The remote api uses threads to read the stream

If your upstream library uses a separate thread to process the incoming messages, you are going to lose 1 of the main advantages of Netty: a low thread count for a high number of connections.

```java
public class RPCInputHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<ByteBuf> {
   RPC upstream = ....;
   PipedInputStream in;
   PipedOutputStream out;

   @Override public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
       in = new PipedInputStream();
       out = new PipedOutputStream(in);
       upstream.startInput(in);
   }

   @Override public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
       out.close(); // This sends EOF to the other pipe
   }

   // This method is called messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext, I) in 5.0.
   public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf msg) throws Exception {
      byte[] data = new byte[msg.readableBytes()];
      msg.readBytes(data);
      out.write(data);
   }
}
```

### Outputstream

Making a custom OutputStream that writes bytes to our connection is simple, most methods map directly over

```java
public class OutputStreamNetty extends OutputStream {
    final Channel channel = ...;
    ChannelFuture lastFuture;

    private void checkFuture() throws IOException {
        if(lastFuture.isDone()) {
            if(lastFuture.cause() != null) {
                throw new IOException("Downstream write problem", lastFuture.cause() );
            }
            lastFuture = null;
        }
    }

    private void addFuture(ChannelFuture f) {
        if(lastFuture == null) {
            lastFuture = f;
        }
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        checkFuture()
        addFuture(channel.close());
    }
    public void flush() throws IOException {
        checkFuture()
        addFuture(channel.flush());
    }
    public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        checkFuture()
        Bytebuf f = channel.alloc().buffer(len);
        f.writeBytes(b, off, len);
        addFuture(channel.write(f));
    }
    public abstract void write(int b) throws IOException {
        checkFuture()
        Bytebuf f = channel.alloc().buffer(1);
        f.writeByte(b);
        addFuture(channel.write(f));
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the quick reply. The RPC lib uses threads for reading the streams. So we will lose the netty advantage here. Does this also mean that we loose the advantage of netty althogether and might as well just use java.io (so no nio). Or is there still some reason to use Netty?

Comment: Will you lose the threading section of Netty, you can still use `EmbeddedChannel` to quickly unit test the implementation, wrap it a with a `SSLContext` to implement SSL support for the protocol, wrap with a `AbstractRemoteAddressFilter` to support a simple firewall, or even create a custom handler around it so it can work over the HTTP protocol, BUT using java sockets will give higher performance, since the data doesn't need to pass a thread boundary when using piped streams. Choose wisely for your future needs.